# reuse UIBezierPath object

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I want to draw an arc and circyle under the arc, and I am using UIBezierPath to do it.

However I want to use only one bezierPath, below code seems dummy. How can I combine the two beizerPath into one and draw the same chart?

```
- (void)drawBackGround {
    UIBezierPath *bgPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHex:BG_ARC_COLOR];
    [color set];
    [bgPath addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:BG_RADIUS startAngle:START_ANGLE endAngle:END_ENGLE clockwise:ANTY_CLOCK_WISE];
    bgPath.lineWidth = BG_ARC_WIDTH;
    bgPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    bgPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    [bgPath stroke];
    UIBezierPath *circylePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [circylePath moveToPoint:self.center];
    [circylePath addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:BG_CIRCYLE_RADIUS startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:CLOCK_WISE];
    [circylePath addLineToPoint:self.center];
    [circylePath fill];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
UIBezierPath *bgPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHex:BG_ARC_COLOR];
[color set];
[bgPath addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:BG_RADIUS startAngle:START_ANGLE endAngle:END_ENGLE clockwise:ANTY_CLOCK_WISE];
bgPath.lineWidth = BG_ARC_WIDTH;
bgPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
bgPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
[bgPath stroke];

[bgPath removeAllPoints];

[bgPath moveToPoint:self.center];
[bgPath addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:BG_CIRCYLE_RADIUS startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:CLOCK_WISE];
[bgPath addLineToPoint:self.center];
[bgPath fill];
```

Comment: Yes `removeAllPoints` did the trick!  what else can achieve similar goals? I am new to the UIBezierPath or Core Graphics, so I am looking for some guidance on how to continue drawing different things and reset some properties.

Comment: @Wingzero Just take a look through the docs for `UIBezierPath` in order to familiarize yourself with the class. You can also drop to a lower level and take a look at the docs for Core Graphics.

Comment: I read the doc, but it saying `Removes all points from the receiver, effectively deleting all subpaths`, I was afraid it will delete my arc as well, so I don't use this API. I am confused why it saying deleting all points, but my arc still valid.

Comment: @Wingzero `UIBezierPath` is just an UIKit wrapper for the underlying Core Graphics equivalent. When you are drawing with Core Graphics it is just like drawing with physical paint brush or pencil, note that you are calling `stroke` before you call `removeAllPoints`, so it is laying down the stroke then removing all the points in the path. I would definitely read the programming guide about Core Graphics, then you will understand what is going on there.